# Getting error on server while sending email with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, security, server

I have hosted a website

> zedsteels.com

and with a subdomain I have given admin login which is admin.zedsteels.com
under that I have a page http://admin.zedsteels.com/ForgotPassword.aspx in which on click of a button an email is sent to the email id

this works perfectly on my local machine but is giving a security error
on this line `SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);`

> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: `System.Security.SecurityException`: Request for the permission of type `'System.Net.Mail.SmtpPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'` failed.

the hosting company told me to add `<trust level="Medium"/>` in the web.config file but when I add this the page does not loads and shows this error

> Configuration Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: This configuration section cannot be used at this path.  This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using `<location allowOverride="false">` from an inherited configuration file.

Comment: Just check your mailbox of gmail. They must have sent you an email about the same like the application wants to access your mail account.

You just need to approve it from the same mail.

Comment: You'll have to talk to your hosting provider again, they have disabled overriding of trust level in web.config of applications.

Comment: i have received **NO** such mail in my gmail for approvel of the access